# AEM Inbox notification not showing?

Tags: aem, sling

I created a Custom workflow added a participant step to user review. Since few days back i am not able to see the participant step Notification in AEM Inbox :(
I checked Permission and everything its works fine, I am using AEM 6.2

My Workflow model:- /etc/workflow/models/HPE_Review.html

The same way my current Running Workflow Instance Also not showing.

Can anybody help me to enable Inbox notification?

Comment: Can you check if your workflow is being triggered and not failing? You can check this from workflow history.

Comment: Have you debugged your participant stop or at least wrote some logs?

Comment: My workflow working fine :-) Inbox notification and Instance also not shwoing [/cq/workflow/content/console.html]

Comment: can you check the logs?